# WCF timeout while using multiple connections

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5

I'm making some calls to a WCF using Parallel.ForEach but most queries return a timeout error.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var svc = new Service.SomethingClient("BasicHttpsBinding_ISvc");

....

svc.Close();
```

I included in my app.config (client) the following tags:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="65535" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

But I keep receiving timeout errors. What should I do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a parallel for each? What is the business motivation? Also, how many times are you calling the service to complete the parallel.foreach?

Comment: I´m using just to process a list faster. I´m using this ForEach with 8 max threads (MaximumDegreeOfParallelism = 8). But it´s a loop of something around 2000 recs

Comment: Does it matter what order the records come back in?

Comment: Actually no =)) ...I put this result in a ConcurrentQueue

Comment: That is good, as parallelism does not guarantee order. I have to run and get something for my daughter, but I will check the question and give some guidance if there is not a good answer within the next hour or so.

Comment: My problem is the large number of timeouts returned by this parallel block. Thank you @GregoryABeamer =)

Comment: I ran into the same issue but run over 100 threads while testing. It should not break a sweat at 8 threads. Is the web service your code? It might be an issue on the server side? Also is the web service running under IIS? If its your code run your code against a HelloWorld function. Then you will know its not the server side having the issue.

Comment: It´s my WCF actually.. and it´s running under IIS =) ...I really don´t know what´s going on... I receive a lot of timeout messages

Answer (score 1):

MaxConnections is not enough. In the service behavior you have to specify maxconcurrentcalls, maxconcurrentinstances and maxconcurrentsessions aswell.

```
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="10"/>
```

Also on the server write "net stat" in the console. There you can see the state of the connections. If they are all waiting, then your server blocks the clients.